# Proving an ideal is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let p be a prime.  show that A = {(px,y) : x,y $\in$ $\mathbb Z$ }  is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z$ x $\mathbb Z$.

I am having trouble showing that A is maximal.  To show A is an ideal, first note that $\mathbb Z$ x $\mathbb Z$ is a commutative ring.  Let (px,y) $\in$ A and let (a,b) $\in$ $\mathbb Z$ x $\mathbb Z$.  Then (px,y)(a,b) = (pxa,yb) $\in$ A.  Thus A is an ideal (Is this sufficient?).  To show A is maximal, I think I could either show that ($\mathbb Z$ x $\mathbb Z$)/A is a field or show that any ideal containing A must equal $\mathbb Z$ x $\mathbb Z$, perhaps by showing a unit must be in in an ideal containing A?.  The main trouble I am having is seeing what the cosets from ($\mathbb Z$ x $\mathbb Z$)/A look like.  Do I consider possible remainders for each coordinate? Any hints as to either approach or an idea for a different approach are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the kernel of the homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(s,t) = s\pmod{p}$?

Comment: I may be missing something, but doesn't this only show that A is an ideal?  How does this play a role in A being maximal?

Comment: @user155242 If $f:R\to S$ is a surjective homomorphism, then $S\cong R/\ker{f}$, a fact that is commonly known as the First Isomorphism Theorem.  If $S$ is a field (which it is, in this case), then $\ker{f}$ is maximal.

Answer (score 2):

An ideal $I$ in a commutative ring $R$ is maximal iff $\frac{R}{I}$ is a field.

In this case it is easy to see $\frac{\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z}{A}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p\times \{0\}$, and  $\mathbb Z_p$ is a field.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the isomorphism?  What do things in ZxZ/A look like?  Is the first coordinate of an ordered pair in a coset the remainder when dividing by p?